# Drop a row in pandas df if a name repeats within the row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which has 10k plus rows. I need to drop a row if a name repeats itself within a row

Example
[image]

Expected
[image]

Second row is deleted as "Chris" appears twice in the same row. I am reasonably new to programming and am not sure where to even begin

Comment: Kindly post actual data, and not pics.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Please be more specific. _I am reasonably new to programming and am not sure where to even begin_ Stack Overflow is not a substitute for guides, tutorials, or documentation, which are likely what you need.

Answer (score 2):

One idea might be to filter on "name" columns, and get [`nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html) names across axis 1. If that number is less than the number of columns then there are duplicates... use this logic to [`boolean index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
# Example data
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name1': ['chris', 'mark', 'chris', 'john'],
                   'Age1': [20, 30, 35, 40],
                   'Name2': ['joe', 'steve', 'chris', 'eric']})


#    Name1  Age1  Name2
# 0  chris    20    joe
# 1   mark    30  steve
# 2  chris    35  chris
# 3   john    40   eric

name_cols = df.filter(like='Name').columns
df_new = df[df[name_cols].nunique(axis=1).eq(len(name_cols))]
print(df_new)
```

[out]

```
   name1  age1  name2
0  chris    20    joe
1   mark    30  steve
3   john    40   eric
```

Comment: This worked a treat. Really appreciate your help mate.

Comment: No bother buddy, glad it helped. Happy coding :)